# How to assign values based on multiple columns in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Is there an elegant way to assign values based on multiple columns in a dataframe in pandas? Let's say I have a dataframe with 2 columns: FruitType and Color.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'FruitType':['apple', 'banana','kiwi','orange','loquat'],
'Color':['red_black','yellow','greenish_yellow', 'orangered','orangeyellow']})
```

I would like to assign the value of a third column, 'isYellowSeedless', based on both 'FruitType' and 'Color' columns.

I have a list of fruits that I consider seedless, and would like to check the Color column to see if it contains the str "yellow".

```
seedless = ['banana', 'loquat']
```

How do I string this all together elegantly?

This is my attempt that didn't work:

```
df[(df['FruitType'].isin(seedless)) & (culture_table['Color'].str.contains("yellow"))]['isYellowSeedless'] = True
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with `mask`:

```
m = (df['FruitType'].isin(seedless)) & (df['Color'].str.contains("yellow"))

df.loc[m, 'isYellowSeedless'] = True
print (df)
             Color FruitType isYellowSeedless
0        red_black     apple              NaN
1           yellow    banana             True
2  greenish_yellow      kiwi              NaN
3        orangered    orange              NaN
4     orangeyellow    loquat             True
```

If need `True` and `False` output:

```
df['isYellowSeedless'] = m
print (df)
             Color FruitType  isYellowSeedless
0        red_black     apple             False
1           yellow    banana              True
2  greenish_yellow      kiwi             False
3        orangered    orange             False
4     orangeyellow    loquat              True
```

For `if-else` by some scalars use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['isYellowSeedless'] = np.where(m, 'a', 'b')
print (df)
             Color FruitType isYellowSeedless
0        red_black     apple                b
1           yellow    banana                a
2  greenish_yellow      kiwi                b
3        orangered    orange                b
4     orangeyellow    loquat                a
```

And for convert to `0` and `1`:

```
df['isYellowSeedless'] = m.astype(int)
print (df)
             Color FruitType  isYellowSeedless
0        red_black     apple                 0
1           yellow    banana                 1
2  greenish_yellow      kiwi                 0
3        orangered    orange                 0
4     orangeyellow    loquat                 1
```

Comment: Really nice solution(s). Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Or you can try

```
df['isYellowSeedless']=df.loc[df.FruitType.isin(seedless),'Color'].str.contains('yellow')
df
Out[546]: 
             Color FruitType isYellowSeedless
0        red_black     apple              NaN
1           yellow    banana             True
2  greenish_yellow      kiwi              NaN
3        orangered    orange              NaN
4     orangeyellow    loquat             True
```

Comment: I really like this one too. Didn't know they could be chained together like that! Thanks!

Comment: @J.W. they are connect by the index. Yw :-)